# SQL - Manually obtain the next available ID for the given format

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, oracle

I'm trying to construct a single, simple SQL SELECT statement that manually provides the next unique ID available for the given format.

For an example, please see the table below.

```
-- Students (Table)
-- ID - Not a primary key
-- Type - Numbering format
+----------+------+
|    ID    | Type |
+----------+------+
|        1 | M    |
|        2 | M    |
|        5 | M    |
|     7056 | F    |
|     7057 | F    |
|     7058 | F    |
|     7090 | F    |
|     7091 | N    |
|    10910 | N    |
|    10911 | N    |
| 99000000 | O    |
| 99000001 | O    |
+----------+------+
```

```
-- Some of the available values:
+---+------+-------+----------+
| M |  F   |   N   |    O     |
+---+------+-------+----------+
| 6 | 7092 | 10912 | 99000002 |
| 7 | 7093 | 10913 | 99000003 |
| 8 | 7094 | 10914 | 99000004 |
+---+------+-------+----------+
```

Here, say I want to get '7092' for the type 'F' as the next value. But if I use the MAX function, it will return '99000002'.

```
SELECT MAX(id)+1 FROM students;
```

If I use the type column, I could get '7091' for the type 'F', but that's not available since it is used by another type.

```
SELECT MAX(id)+1 FROM students WHERE type = 'F';
```

This also does not work.

```
SELECT MAX(id)+1 
FROM   students 
WHERE  type = 'F'
       AND id NOT IN ( SELECT DISTINCT id FROM students)
```

I am not able to change the database structure. If so, for the given scenario, is there a way (single SELECT statement) to get the next available ID for the selected type (e.g.: type F)?
I use Oracle 10g, but MySQL and SQL Server are okay as well.

```
CREATE TABLE students (
  id   NUMBER,
  type CHAR(1)
);

INSERT INTO students VALUES (1, 'M');
INSERT INTO students VALUES (2, 'M');
INSERT INTO students VALUES (5, 'M');

INSERT INTO students VALUES (7056, 'F');
INSERT INTO students VALUES (7057, 'F');
INSERT INTO students VALUES (7058, 'F');
INSERT INTO students VALUES (7090, 'F');

INSERT INTO students VALUES (7091, 'N');
INSERT INTO students VALUES (10910, 'N');
INSERT INTO students VALUES (10911, 'N');

INSERT INTO students VALUES (99000000, 'O');
INSERT INTO students VALUES (99000001, 'O');
```

I would be grateful for any assistance. In any case, thank you for your time.

Comment: I don't see the point of having consecutive ids. The only important aspect of a primary key column is that it needs to be UNIQUE. No one really looks or cares at the specific values it has. As long as it uniquely identifies a row all is good.

Comment: I don't understand - why is 7 the next available value, and not 3? (That, quite apart from the bigger question: what is the real-life application of this exercise?) Also, what does "type" have to do with the problem? Why would you look at id for type = M in an attempt to solve your problem? That makes no sense - please explain better. One more question - what data type is `text`?

Comment: Why are you trying to reinvent the wheel, just use an identity column

Comment: If you're not able to change the database to suit requirements then speak to management about why they are tying your hands. Use the right tool for the job. Tricks such as `MAX(id)` have major concurrency and manageability issues

Comment: @Charlieface, Unfortunately, that's a no, no.  This is an old table with many values, and this is linked with other tables and programs as well. So, it won't be easy. I'm just trying to make my task easier. I'm also curious. That's all.

Comment: I had to update the question to address the comments.

Answer (score 1):

**You're looking for the gaps, in consequence you're looking for the values `NOT IN` the id list.**

The following query will give you a list of all the id's `NOT IN` the table.

```sql
SELECT sub_id FROM (
    SELECT id+1 as sub_id FROM students
)sub_table WHERE sub_id NOT IN (
    SELECT id FROM students
);
```

Then you can select the `MIN()` of that list:

```sql
SELECT MIN(sub_id) FROM (
    SELECT id+1 as sub_id FROM students
)sub_table WHERE sub_id NOT IN (
    SELECT id FROM students
);
```

*Bear in mind that this will work only if you already have at least one id and it won't start from 1 unless you already have the id 1.*

***Notice: that the first query only gives you the list of all the gaps plus the next available id.***

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```sql
SELECT COALESCE(MAX(id) + 1,1) AS next_id
FROM   (
  SELECT id,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) AS rn
  FROM   students
)
WHERE id = rn;
```

or:

```sql
SELECT COALESCE(MAX(id + 1), 1) AS next_id
FROM   students
WHERE  CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF = 1
START WITH id = 1
CONNECT BY PRIOR id + 1 = id;
```

Which, for your sample data, both output:

> | NEXT_ID |
> | --- |
> | 3 |

*Note: These queries will both return `1` if the first `id` value is deleted.*

However, a better solution would be to use a sequence and let that handle generating the keys and not to worry about gaps between values.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=4130e4bef601d37f932820632ad93078)*

Answer (score 0):

Just use group by type after where
SELECT MAX(id)+1 FROM students WHERE type = 'F' GROUP BY type